# AWS claudia create error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, claudiajs

I'm a newbie to Claudia and AWS. When I try to deploy my claudia chat bot onto AWS using

```
claudia create --region us-east-1 --api-module bot
```

command, a lambda function already exists error occurs:

```
ResourceConflictException: Function already exist
```

There is no such a role or lambda function in my AWS. Can someone tell me how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

just add `--name <NAME>` to prevent name conflict.